# Is there a reason unittest isn't working here?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm not certain if I'm missing something completely obvious, but every time I call upon unittest.main() my commandline output reads out:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

It should say that I've run two tests, though, given the code here:

```
import unittest
from Chap11Lesson2 import Employee

    class EmployeeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """Setting up a variable for use in the test methods"""
        self.employee1 = Employee("Lucas", "Grillos", 20000)

    def give_default_raise(self):
        """Testing to see if 5000 is added properly"""
        money = 25000
        self.employee1.give_raise()
        self.assertEqual(self.employee1.salary, money)

    def give_custom_raise(self):
        """Testing to see if 10000 is raised properly"""
        money = 35000
        self.employee1.give_raise(10000)
        self.assertEqual(self.employee1.salary, money)

unittest.main()
```

Here's the class that it's testing from:

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.salary = salary

    def give_raise(self, salary_raise = None):
        if salary_raise:
            self.salary = self.salary + salary_raise
        else:
            self.salary = self.salary + 5000

    def print_salary(self):
        print(self.salary)
```

I've never had a problem like this before, so I'm not certain what to do. I'm learning Python from Eric Matthes' Python Crash Course, the 2016 edition, if that's any reference. This problem hasn't appeared in the other lessons that I've done from it either.

Here's what I've tried:

I've tried fiddling around with the give_raise(self, salary_raise=None) method, and changing up how that worked in case I had messed something up internally there but I don't see why that would affect the testing.

I've tried deleting it and rewriting it once again (since it's not a lot of code) in hopes that I just forgot something silly, but if I did then I forgot it a second time.

Apologies in advance if it's a very simple fix, and apologies if there's anything wrong with the way I've formatted this question, or if this isn't a forum for questions like this--this is my first time posting here.

Comment: I apologize that I didn't add docstrings to my functions for clarification on what they do.

Comment: prefix your test methods with 'test' to get them to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test methods need to have names beginning with `test_` for the unittest runner to find them.

Call your tests `test_give_default_raise` and `test_give_custom_raise`.

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid I forgot to do...

Thanks so much for you help in any case, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

The class EmployeeTest(unittest.TestCase):, should have test_ methods to be run the unittest module.
so try this:

```
import unittest
from Chap11Lesson2 import Employee

class EmployeeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Setting up a variable for use in the test methods"""
        self.employee1 = Employee("Lucas", "Grillos", 20000)

    def test_give_default_raise(self):
        """Testing to see if 5000 is added properly"""
        money = 25000
        self.employee1.give_raise()
        self.assertEqual(self.employee1.salary, money)

    def test_give_custom_raise(self):
    """Testing to see if 10000 is raised properly"""
        money = 35000
        self.employee1.give_raise(10000)
        self.assertEqual(self.employee1.salary, money)

unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method names so they're prefixed with 'test' for the test methods and it should run.